# $\sum_{i=1}^{k} \binom{n}{i} \le (\frac{en}{k})^k$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

prove $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} \binom{n}{i} \le (\frac{en}{k})^k$$

this inequality comes after:

1. show that for every $1\le k\le n$ and $0 \lt x \lt 1 $ $$ \binom{n}{k}x^k \le (1+x)^n \le e^{xn}$$
2. show that$$ \binom {n}{k} \le (\frac{en}{k})^k$$

I solved the first two parts, and now to solve the last part I used $x = \frac{k}{n}$

so I got :

$$(1+x)^n = (1+\frac{k}{n})^n = \sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}(\frac{k}{n})^i \le e^{xn} = e^k$$

multiply both sides of the equation by $(\frac{n}{k})^k$ to get:
$$ \sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}(\frac{n}{k})^{k-i} \le (\frac{en}{k})^k$$

How can I conclude now the final step?

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k} \binom{n}{i} \le \sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}(\frac{n}{k})^{k-i}$$

Comment: Should it be $$\left(\frac{en}{k}\right)^k$$ in the title and in the statement to prove?

Comment: yes, I fixed it

Comment: hint: $1 \le k \le n$

Comment: What is $k$ in this problem? It seems that $\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i}$ is just equal to $2^n$. What did you mean?

Comment: K is fixed between 1 and n, I fixed some notations in the problem, maybe now its more clear, I also add a liitle mistake, i thought the sum is from 1 to n but it is actually from 1 to k, which makes it easier to prove, and I can easily see it by the hint $1\le k \le n $ , but now, why does the sum goes from 1 to k? is it not true also for the sum from 0 to k?

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$ \binom{n}{i} \geq \left( \frac{n}{i} \right)^i . $$
You get
$$ \sum_{i=1}^k\left( \frac{n}{i} \right)^i\leq \sum_{i=1}^k\binom{n}{i} \leq \left( \frac{en}{k} \right)^k .  $$
Since
$$ \sum_{i=1}^k\left( \frac{n}{i} \right)^i\leq k \left( \frac{n}{k} \right)^k  $$
and obviously
$$ k \left( \frac{n}{k} \right)^k \leq e^k \left( \frac{n}{k} \right)^k $$
the inequality holds true.